# How do I sort an array in Perl if not all of the elements in the array are defined?

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

How do I sort an array if not all of the elements in the array are defined?

```
my @names;
$names[0]  = "andrei";
$names[1]  = "serghei";
$names[7]  = "valerii";
$names[10] = "alexandr";

@names = sort @names; # aint working.
```

I apologize guys, I just don't get how to post questions here properly. I tried the FAQ, I just don't get it.

Comment: What do you mean by "aint working"?  What exactly doesn't work?  What result do you expect?  Can you show the output of your program and explain why it is wrong?

Comment: to print array (and void error msg) i di it this way.  foreach (@names) 
{
    if (defined) {
        say;
        }  else { 
            say "value undefined";
        }  
}     i need to sort it somehow

Comment: I just wan't to know why you would make a sparse array like that intentionally in the first place?

Comment: im learning. thats just for example, to practice working with arrays, to learn and understand better by doing.

Comment: Are you trying to sort the defined values but keep the index positions?

Comment: at this point i dont care about index positions. i guess. all i need is print them out in order.

Comment: If you have `use warnings;`, you'll get a lot of warnings when you run your script: `Use of uninitialized value in sort at ./foo.pl line 13.`. If you don't have `use warnings;`, *you should*. You say you want to print them "in order". Print what? In what order? You have an 11-element array, 7 of whose elements are undefined, but they're still elements of the array. If you want to sort the undefined values along with the strings, you can inhibit warnings locally. If you want to print just the defined elements, please update your question to say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

my @names;
$names[0]  = "andrei";
$names[1]  = "serghei";
$names[7]  = "valerii";
$names[10] = "alexandr";

@names = sort grep { defined } @names;

for my $name ( @names ) {
    say $name;
}
```

The `grep { defined }` takes `@names` and removes all the undefined values from `@names`.

If you don't want to remove the undefined stuff, you can do this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

my @names;
$names[0]  = "andrei";
$names[1]  = "serghei";
$names[7]  = "valerii";
$names[10] = "alexandr";

no warnings qw(uninitialized);
@names = sort @names;
use warnings qw(uninitialized);

for my $name ( @names ) {
    say $name if defined $name;;
}
```

The `no warnings qw(initialized);` will turn off uninitialized warnings. I know that I'll run into trouble with unitialized warnging with `sort`, so I simply turn off the uninitialized warnings, and turn them right back on right after the `sort`.

Answer (score 6):

`undef` will is *lower* than any non-empty string, this is why it get's sorted at the beginning. What you probably want is a "cleaned" result array with all `undef` elements removed? If so, here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @names;
$names[1] = 'alpha';
$names[3] = 'gamma';
$names[10] = 'beta';
@names = sort grep { defined } @names;

print Dumper(\@names);

# $VAR1 = [
#   'alpha',
#   'beta',
#   'gamma'
# ];
```

Answer (score 5):

To get rid of the undefined elements and sort the rest:

```
sort grep defined, @names
```

To place the undefined elements at the start:

```
sort { !defined($a) && !defined($b) ? 0
     : !defined($a) ? -1
     : !defined($b) ? +1
     : $a cmp $b
} @names
```

To place the undefined elements at the end:

```
sort { !defined($a) && !defined($b) ? 0
     : !defined($a) ? +1
     : !defined($b) ? -1
     : $a cmp $b
} @names
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy one-liner to print your array including gaps:

```
print join "\n", @names;
```

Or if you want to put 'undefined' values in:

```
print join "\n", map {$_ || "undef"} @names;
```

If you want to trim out the undefined values, use `grep` as *ukautz* suggested in his answer.

```
print join "\n", grep {defined} @names;
```

You can use the same approach to get the valid indices:

```
@idx = grep {defined $names[$_]} keys @names;
```

The above can be used if you wanted to sort the defined values and then insert them back in the defined positions.  Sort of like an in-place sort.

```
@sorted = grep {defined} sort @names;
map {$names[$idx[$_]] = $sorted[$_]} keys @sorted;
```